# You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server on NGINX

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I am facing an issue with following line as

```
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server
```

Server is on `nginx`. Any help what to do with that ?

Comment: The user the server is running as, does probably not have the correct permissions on the folder corresponding to `/phpmyadmin/`. Check the folder permissions. This seems **off-topic** to me, better post your question on http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your support for that. Need to know what is the correct permission to run the above path ? 777 ?

Comment: `777` is quite insecure, but should work... Take a look at the documentation of nginx, check the logs on your server, find out which user nginx run as, and fix the permissions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if the nginx user is set to `nginx` in the config file, you can use the command

```
chown nginx phpmyadmin
```

and then give `phpmyadmin` permission `755`.